# Joining list of nest/ggplot2 generated images to two columns with consistent proportions

Tags: r, ggplot2

In summary, I would like to split a list of plots created using *nest* and *ggplot2* to two columns. The problem I have had in my approaches is that elements in different subplots end up having more or less inconsistent dimensions because subplots have different heights (different number of elements in each groups, possibly exclusion of x-axis labels etc.).

Following example code uses the main tidyverse packages. I first generate some dummy data using *mtcars*; cars are split to random groups and each car is assigned an in-group position.

```
dummy <- mtcars %>% 
    mutate(group = sample(1:10, n(), replace = TRUE)) %>%
    filter(group < 6) %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(position = 1:n())
```

The actual code produces a list of subplots (plots) and information about number of elements in each group (heights).

```
## install patchwork via:
## devtools::install_github("thomasp85/patchwork")

plots <- dummy %>%
    nest(-group, .key = "data") %>%
    mutate(plots = map(data, ~ggplot(data = .x, aes(x = position, y = hp)) +
                                      geom_bar(stat="identity") +
                                coord_flip()),
           heights = purrr::map(data,  ~ nrow(.)) %>% unlist())
g.plot <- patchwork::wrap_plots(plots$plots, ncol = 1, heights = plots$heights)
```

Function *wrap_plots* is able to produce a nice one-panel image using information about heights (included image panel A). When there is a large number of images to the plot, the one-column plot is not practical. I would, therefore, kindly ask help on how to turn the output of the above code (panel A) to the hoped output (panel B). Panel C exaggerates the problematic effect I have had using different image concatenation approaches.

**Current output and hoped output**

[image]

Comment: Why not using 2 cols as in `patchwork::wrap_plots(plots$plots, ncol = 2, heights = plots$heights)`?

Comment: I believe that ncol does not allow different heights between related column levels (for all columns first row has height[1], second row height[2], ...). So that results something like Panel C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try setting the panel size to fixed dimensions and then arranging the gtables together,

```
library(egg)
library(gridExtra)
lg <- purrr::map2(plots$plots, plots$heights, 
                  function(p,h) gtable_frame(ggplotGrob(p), 
                                             height =unit(h/10,'npc'), #tweak
                                             width =unit(0.7,'npc')))  #tweak

grid.arrange(gtable_rbind(lg[[1]],lg[[2]], egg::.dummy_gtable),
             gtable_rbind(lg[[3]],lg[[4]], egg::.dummy_gtable), ncol=2)
```

(tested with `set.seed(12)`; I don't know what `sample()` OP had)

Comment: Really nice solution! Thank you for the help!